# Why does "nslookup -type=mx YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM" return a valid mail exchanger?

Tags: email, nslookup

For the first one it returns:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM        MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = mail.h-email.net
```

Also if you just duplicate the tld like

```
C:\Users\dmorri>nslookup -type=mx gmail.com.com.com.com.
```

You get an odd mail exchanger:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
gmail.com.com.com.com   MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx203.inbound-mx.net
gmail.com.com.com.com   MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx203.inbound-mx.org
```

How are you going to know when its really an invalid domain?

We don't want the domain look valid when it really is not!

Comment: https://com.com/legal "Com.com allows users to conduct searches by visiting sub-domains of Com.com. For example, if you visited "example.com.com" you might reach a page with information about "example." "

Comment: @eis: LOL I get a malware warning on com.com

Comment: Define "invalid" in "How are you going to know when its really an invalid domain?".

Answer (score 31):

I don't know if there is really that much of a "why" to talk about, probably more a change of perspective to see this for what it is.

Someone has registered `comoo.com`, someone has registered `com.com`.

These domains exist in the real world and while you clearly don't like them, that doesn't make them invalid in any technical sense.

As with any domain, the owner can add whatever records they like (in your example for subdomains of these).

Comment: Yeah..I am good with comoo.com and com.com etc. What I  don't like is gmail.com.com.com.com (add as many com as you want) or YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM can match those. But I guess that is what wildcarding does?

Comment: @DarrellMorris Well... if someone owns `comoo.com` then they can add whatever records they want, whether those are wildcards or not doesn't really make mucch difference from where we stand.  What is the overall goal, in what context is `YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM` an actual concern?

Comment: @DarrellMorris it's not so much about "wildcarding", it's about "if you control `foo.bar` then you control everything that ends with `.foo.bar`"

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Clearly the *actual* concern with those mail aliases is that they'd get mail addressed to someone else because of typos.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I assume that you mean that they would get mail *intended* for someone else but *addressed* to them? That is indeed one possible interpretation, which would be tricky to "fix" in software as it's about intent rather than validity/correctness. For one thing, if you start overriding the stated delivery address based on some heuristics(?) that can cause the exact same type of problem but in a worse way; the user entered the correct address but the system changed it to something else and delivered the message to the wrong person.

Answer (score 22):

The answer is pretty simple.

The domain name `yahoo.comyahoo.comoo.com` belongs to the owners of `comoo.com`, and so those people can do whatever they want with it. The reason that `yahoo.comyahoo.comoo.com` returns an MX record is that the owners of `comoo.com` decided to make it do that.

Likewise, the domain name `gmail.com.com.com.com` belongs to the owners of `com.com`, and so those people can do whatever they want with it. They have decided to make `gmail.com.com.com.com` return an MX record.

I'm not sure why you think these domain names are invalid, or that there's some kind of problem here. These domain names are completely valid and there's no problem. Everything is working exactly as it's supposed to.

Perhaps you're thinking that the first part of a domain name is the most significant part and the last parts are not so significant. Actually, the opposite is true: the last parts are the most significant and the first part is the least significant.

It's just like how if you send a letter to Michigan City, Indiana, then it will go to the state of Indiana, not the state of Michigan. The fact that the address starts with the word "Michigan" doesn't matter, because the most significant part of the address is the end, not the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

You are asking about a different domain:

```
# dig YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM MX @9.9.9.9
; <<>> DiG 9.16.8 <<>> YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM MX @9.9.9.9
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5554
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM.  IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM. 3595  IN  MX  5 mail.h-email.net.

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 9.9.9.9#53(9.9.9.9)
;; WHEN: (...) 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 85
```

You are receiving a mail exchange DNS answer for COMOO.COM, the last bit (and valid domain name) for your misspelled query:

```
# dig COMOO.COM MX @9.9.9.9

; <<>> DiG 9.16.8 <<>> COMOO.COM MX @9.9.9.9
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3094
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;COMOO.COM.         IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
COMOO.COM.      3600    IN  MX  5 mail.h-email.net.

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 9.9.9.9#53(9.9.9.9)
;; WHEN: (...) 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70
```

Same for `gmail.com.com.com.com` - the domain `com.com` exists and has an MX entry which you can query. `gmail.com.com.com.com` looks like a machine on a subdomain of that main domain.

Comment: Do you really think those exist? The MX records look suspect. And you can just keep adding .com and they will all work. Seem odd to me. And if I do for another domain like yahoo.com.com.com I get the same MX records. If it is just taking the last part...Is there a way to tell NSLookup not to do that? Or find out what NSLOOKUP is using like DIG does?

Comment: @DarrellMorris They may not exist specifically but that MX seems to be responsible for "*.com.com".  They have nothing to do with Yahoo or Google, though.

Comment: Makes sense. So I need a way to make nslookup use all the info I sent it (not just the last two parts or whatever its doing).

Comment: @DarrellMorris Pretty sure nslookup already used what you gave it. It just so happens that the owner of `COMOO.COM` has added records (wildcard?) such that `YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM` does have an `MX` (same idea for your other example).

Comment: @DarrellMorris It is against the hierarchical model used in domains to enforce "the first part".  The lookup is recursive: First for ".com", then for "com.com" then with com.com's name server for MX entries of which there may be "*.com.com".  If that matches it is valid per Internet standards.

Comment: Interesting. So there is no way to know if this is valid or not for what I input exactly? Btw...It seems gmail.com.com.com.com is matching what com.com.com returns AND not com.com (which is a different mailexchanger server). Hopefully someone has an idea on how to detect this issue/situation.

Comment: @DarrellMorris Basically according to the Internet standards everything is working exactly as it should.  So, you will not get a different answer from a name server.  If you wish to make sure no-one has mis-typed the query you need to specify what is a valid query and what isn't. There is no reason the owners of "com.com" shouldn't want to create and use "gmail.com.com.com.com".  The rules what is "valid" for you and what isn't need to be made by yourself.

Comment: @DarrellMorris The point is that from a technical perspective both `YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COMOO.COM` and `gmail.com.com.com.com` are valid. There is no technical problem shown in the question. If you have a specific problem, can you clarify what it is?

Comment: Yes. So lets say a user comes in with an email of xyz@gmail.com.com.com.com. If we validate then it will say that domain is valid (it really isn't). So we are thinking of removing duplication in this case gmail.com.com.com.com to gmail.com. But that doesn't work so well on something like the odd YAHOO.COMYAHOO.COm.COMOO.COM record. ;-) If NSLookup or these users would not have put wildcards like this in there we would easily see its not valid and be able to massage/manipulate the data using algorithms to retry with. ;-)

Comment: @DarrellMorris It is valid, though (from a DNS perspective, as for whether such an email address exists, I suppose is a different question)

Comment: @DarrellMorris Apologies but why are you saying "it really isn't"?  It is.  The rules you are applying for "validity" come from you, others may have other rules!  What are your rules?

Comment: Yeah...Because someone added wildcards...I think you would find most of these truly not valid.....Just re-directs. I guess we will have to manipulate records that match to another value sometimes like gmail.com.com.com to gmail.com

Comment: @DarrellMorris That sounds like creating a bigger problem from something that either is not a problem at all or otherwise is a smaller problem.

Comment: Ned64 you are correct though..I guess we are defining the rules to deal with these wildcards. Hakan...Maybe we are and something we will discuss. I appreciate everyone chiming in that these domains are valid if though they look really fishy and probably just wildcard entries. ;-)

Comment: @DarrellMorris I'd like to add that "auto-correcting" addresses is dangerous too. As an example, I often receive mails at my address <name>@gmail.com meant for somebody else <same-name>@mail.com (note the missing "g"). Both are actual valid email providers but some services seem to 'correct' mail.com to gmail.com, leading to the mails being delivered to me instead of their mailbox. Some services even allow me to login or reset the password! With a proper Double Opt-In this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @James_pic Wildcards do exist in DNS. If you perform a zone transfer, they'll be returned explicitly. However, most servers restrict zone transfer access, so you may not be able to tell where they exist. But if the server returns a valid record for a random name, it's usually due to a wildcard.

Comment: @James_pic "as far as DNS is concerned, there is no such thing as a wildcard" You may want to have a look at section 4.3.3 of RFC 1034 (canonical reference on the DNS), whose title is "Wildcards".

Comment: @DarrellMorris domains are essentially read backwards. This is how they are designed. Nslookup "only looks at the last two parts" because that's what's relevant if the MX record is for "*.com.com". Again, this is a feature, not a defect. It's not broken, and "fixing" it will almost certainly cause problems down the road.

Comment: Please @DarrellMorris for the love of the internet, do not do any "validity check" of email addresses. Please. Way way too often am I not allowed to use my@domain.com as an email address. Because "it's not a valid email address".